Image only one pixel tall when being displayed in CTkScrollableFrame
I'm using CustomTkInter with Python and I'm trying to get an image to be displayed in a CTkScrollableFrame widget such that the image (which is larger than the frame) is vertically scrollable using the widget. The image is appearing, but only has one pixel's worth of height. I can see the full width, but only one pixel of height. In the below image, the Image in question is the line of peppered black and white near the top.

Here is my code. I create the frame, find the image, place it in a label, and place the label in the frame. The commented-out line is where I tried resizing the label to the image, but it had no visible effect.

import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import warnings

import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk


__location__ = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))


ctk.set_appearance_mode("light")

root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("WHERE IS MY IMAGE")
root.geometry("900x600")
root.after(0, lambda:root.state('zoomed')) # open in maximized state


frame_waiver = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(master=root)
frame_waiver.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.0, relwidth=1, relheight=0.7, anchor=tk.N)

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='CTkLabel Warning')
waiver = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(__location__, 'waiver_liability.png')))
label_waiver = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame_waiver, image=waiver, text='')
label_waiver.photo = waiver
# label_waiver.configure(width=waiver.width(), height=waiver.height())
label_waiver.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.0, relheight = 0.5, anchor=tk.N)


root.mainloop()



Since putting the label using place() will not adjust the size of its parent frame, so the size of the parent frame will be 1x1 in pixel by default.
